# How to dynamically delete object using django formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, inline-formset

Django says, i should render `inline formset` this way:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form.id }}
    {{ form.field_1 }} 
    {{ form.field_2 }}
    <button type="button"> delete </button>
{% endfor %}
<button type="submit"> submit </button>
```

Ok. But what if i want to delete some formset objects (`form`) dynamically? User press `delete` button - i remove `form` from the DOM, i use ajax to remove object, related to the `form` from the DATABASE. It works ok till this point. But when user clicks `submit` - my views.py trying to validate formset:

```
filled_formset = OrderItemFormSet(request.POST, instance=order)
if filled_formset.is_valid():
```

and raises error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /order/cart/  
"'orderitem_set-0-id'"  
...\market\ordersys\views.py in show_cart  
59.   if filled_formset.is_valid():
```

I think it happend because `form` objects were displayed by django with some regularity (first form got id = `orderitem_set-0-id`, second = `orderitem_set-1-id` etc.) And when i deleted first `form` from the DOM, the regularity was broken - there is no more `form` with `orderitem_set-0-id`. But `is_valid()` still trying to get it `dict["orderitem_set-0-id"]`.

I could use some black magic, substituting django's technical information, displayed in the DOM, restoring disrupted regularity, but is there a better way?

Could you tell me how to properly dynamically delete formset items, please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got no answer for some time, so i did not find any better solution than below. Maybe someome will find it useful.

Ok, the trick is - to have `{{form.DELETE}}` for any `form` in your `formset` in template. It renders as a checkbox (i made it invisible) and i made JS to make it "checked" whenever user press "delete" button. After user press "submit" button, every `form`, marked for deletion, will NOT be validated by the view during `filled_formset.is_valid()`. This lets you delete object from database with ajax behind the scene.

> The problem was that an ERROR was raised during formset validation. Caused by the form of an object, which was already deleted from database with ajax.

So there are all components:

views.py

```
def show_cart(request):
    OrderItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Order, OrderItem, form=OrderItemForm, extra=0, can_delete=True)
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=request.session['order'])

    if request.method == 'GET':                                                                  
        formset = OrderItemFormSet(instance=order)
        return render(request, 'ordersys/cart.html', {'formset': formset})

    elif request.method == 'POST':            
        filled_formset = OrderItemFormSet(request.POST, instance=order)
        if filled_formset.is_valid():                
            filled_formset.save()
            return redirect('catalog:index')
        else:
            return render(request, 'ordersys/cart.html', {'formset': filled_formset})
```

cart.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form.id }}
        {{ form.DELETE|add_class:"not_displayed" }}                   # custom filter
        <img src="{{ form.instance.spec_prod.product.picture.url }}">
            {{ form.quantity.label_tag }}
            {{ form.quantity }}
            {{ form.errors }}
            <button type="button">Delete</button>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Next, if user press 'DELETE' button, my JavaScript
1. hides `form` with `$(item).css('display', 'none');`
2. makes checked `form.DELETE` checkbox with `ItemDelCheckbox.prop('checked', true);`
3. sends ajax request to delete item from database (otherwise if user refreshes the page, the item still in the cart)

views.py

```
def delete_order_item(request):            # meets the ajax request
    item_id = int(request.POST['item_id'])
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, pk=int(request.POST['order_id']))
    order.remove_item(item_id)
    if order.is_empty():                   # if the last item is deleted
        order.untie(request.session)
        order.delete()
    return HttpResponse()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually creating the hidden field using {{ form.DELETE }}, you can probably use 'can_delete' while instantiating the formset which does the same. For eg,

```
ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm, can_delete=True)
```

Refer [can_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete)

Comment: And if you don' t add {{ form.DELETE }} how deleted forms are detected?